# UFW inactive but IP forwarding blocked

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, ufw

I have two VMs (in VirtualBox), both of them are Ubuntu Server 18.10 (cosmic):

- the first one, `Server`, has two NICs: one in NAT, the other one in intnet
- the second machine, `Client`, has only one NIC, in intnet, to communicate with `Server`

Now I would like to make `Server` a gateway, and so I've enabled IP forwarding (by modifying `sysctl.conf`, restarted it and so on.

When I check `sudo ufw status` (on `Server`), it says `inactive`. OK. But I cannot ping any external IP address on `Client` until I set iptables on `Server` with

> `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE`

As soon as I press Enter, ping command typed in `Client` does work. But why, since UFW is inactive??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UFW being inactive has nothing to do with it.

In `iptables` parlance, you *must* have a `MASQUERADE` rule set in the NAT table for traffic to work being forwarded outbound regardless.  Otherwise, the system won't know what to do with the packets.  This remains the case even if you directly use `iptables` to manipulate the `*filter` rules (to set `INPUT`, `OUTPUT`, etc. access control lists and such, or even to just `ALLOW` all traffic on those policysets) - NAT always is in play and you have to add the NAT rule to make forwarded traffic masquerade out to the Internet as the server's primary IP.

Therefore, you must add the rule whether using UFW or not in order to get the system to understand how to translate the packet and route it via the server to the Internet, and thus how to automatically handle the reverse routing as well.

---

[This Github GIST](https://gist.github.com/kimus/9315140#nat) which I found has a pretty good explanation of what to do for this for UFW:

> The final step is to add NAT to ufw’s configuration. Add the following
>   to /etc/ufw/before.rules just before the filter rules.
>
> ```
> # NAT table rules
> *nat
> :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
>
> # Forward traffic through eth0 - Change to match you out-interface
> -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
>
> # don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these nat table rules won't
> # be processed
> COMMIT
> ```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I thought that ufw was more on less a "frontend" for iptables? If not, is there a mean to "disable" iptables?

Comment: @Greg82 it's not a case of disabling `iptables` - you still need the `MASQUERADE` rule either way.  ANd yes, UFW is a frontend for easy management of `iptables` rules, but that only is insomuchas to make it easy to manage access rules, `MASQUERADE` rules, etc. need to be edited into the `ufw` configuration file for rules to do before it applies access rules.

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar observation, however in my case below is happening

1. I have disabled ufw
2. After I reboot the ubuntu server, the PING test does not traverse from one interface to other interface
3. If I enabled/disable ufw and retry, it works

I am using Ubuntu 18.04